Camera preview with transparent area
I want to create a fullscreen camera preview where the middle of the view is a rectangle. Everything inside the rectangle should be opaque and everything outside should be semi-transparent:

The solid lines indicates opaque parts of the preview (the grey rectangle) and the dotted lines are the semi-transparent parts.
Currently, I'm using the standard AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer but I don't see a way to apply any alpha to the output let alone applying an alpha to only some areas. Is this possible?

UPDATE:
Working MRE:
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        
        guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: Unable to initialize back camera: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CameraViewController {
        return CameraViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CameraViewController, context: Context) {}
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CameraView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

I found that AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer has a opacity property that can be set to make the preview transparent, but still don't see a way to make an rectangle that's opaque.

What have you tried so far? Could you show the code?

Forgive me if this requires setting up for you but I'm playing around with this. I simply added self.previewLayer.opacity = 0.5 after this line and added a  Text("BACKGROUND") before the preview in the demo executable. This seems to make it transparent (see my update).

Also found this post but its a decade old

I've tried the Aespa library that you mentioned above. So I will use this project to give you the solution. The entire screen is an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, to achieve your desired UI, you need to:

Wrap the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer into a view instead of a controller's view as they did in the library.

Nothing much on this step, open the Preview file, then declare a custom controller, let's say PreviewController.
final class PreviewController: UIViewController {
    let previewContainer = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(previewContainer)
        previewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            transparentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            transparentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            transparentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            transparentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

struct Preview: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PreviewController, context: Context) {
        ...
        if previewLayer.superlayer == nil {
            uiViewController.previewContainer.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        }
    }
}



Add a cameraOverlayView above the preview layer on step 1. Imagine the red view at center is your opaque view, another are semi-transparent parts.


final class CameraOverlayView: UIView {
    private var container: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        return v
    }()

    private var top = UIView()
    private let bottom = UIView()

    private var centerContent: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        return v
    }()

    private let focusView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        addSubview(container)
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        top.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        top.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

        bottom.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

        container.addArrangedSubview(top)
        container.addArrangedSubview(centerContent)
        container.addArrangedSubview(bottom)

        let padding = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 300) / 2
        let leading = UIView()
        leading.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        leading.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: padding).isActive = true
        let trailing = UIView()
        trailing.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        trailing.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: padding).isActive = true

        centerContent.addArrangedSubview(leading)
        centerContent.addArrangedSubview(focusView)
        centerContent.addArrangedSubview(trailing)
        focusView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        focusView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
    }
}

I've fixed the constants. You can change them later or inject them via parameter / function.
Now add the view to PreviewController and make sure it's above previewContainer.
final class PreviewController: UIViewController {
    private var cameraOverlayView: CameraOverlayView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        cameraOverlayView = CameraOverlayView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(cameraOverlayView)
        cameraOverlayView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cameraOverlayView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            cameraOverlayView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            cameraOverlayView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            cameraOverlayView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

Output:


I arrived at similar results with this:
.mask(
    Rectangle()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .opacity(0.5)
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
                .opacity(1)
        )
)```

Basically a `mask` modifier to the `viewModel.preview`.

Oh, so what is your main purpose? Do you answer the question by yourself? I thought you were supposed to support a lower version?

Could you try it and let me know what you think? Hard to judge the implications

I fully appreciate the tip. I only got it working just now but it's good that it supports earlier versions.

From my perspective, your solution worked well too, let's say it's a kind of SwiftUI version and mine is turning back to UIKit.

I updated the post with a MRE for future references. My apologies you had to fiddle with Aespa. I didn't have the MRE when I made this post. Cool vegeta in the background tho

Or maybe that's Goku...

Haha, you noticed it xD. Anyway, happy coding.
